# marking substring in a string without changing its content

Tags: php, string

suppose i have a function called `F($input)` and defined in one file.

and i don't know what is its source ,that is i can not see the file content. i only call the function F by my input string and the function return another string that may consist of my input once or more times.

i want a way to recognize my input string in the returned value if any.

for example suppose the function F is below:

```
function F($input){
    return 'foo'.$input.'bar';
}
```

and i call `F('bar')` and this return `foobarbar`.
i now don't know which substring of this, is my input parameter `bar`. first `bar` or second?
i am looking for a way [for example] to mark every character of my input string before sending to F and every manipulation on it within F, maintain marked characters. eventually the returned value of F consist of for example `foo*bar*bar` that first `bar` is distinguishable.

note: mark must not change string content. that is for the marked $input, `($input=='bar')` must not return false.

Comment: Save for calling `F('*'.$input.'*');`, no, cannot be done, a string is a _simple_ type.

Comment: Hi. not unless some extra attributes are attached.

Comment: seems very confused with unclear intentions, downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You could return a decorator rather than the string. The object would contain the additional markup and allow you to know what the string positions are. If you override __toString(), you can return the normal string and most operations should keep working.

```
class SubstringPositionDecorator
{
    private $string;
    private $start;
    private $length;

    function __construct($string, $start, $length)
    {
        $this->string = $string;
        $this->start = $start;
        $this->length = $length;
    }

    function __toString()
    {
        return $this->string;
    }

    // Additional functions to access the substring information
}

function F($input)
{
    // Find string position...

    return new SubstringPositionDecorator('foo' . $input . 'bar', 3, 3);
}

$annotedString = F('bar');
```

Comment: I updated the code. I'd be clearer, but you need to clarify your question as well.

Comment: thanks, but you change the file content. i don't want to change code of function `F`.

Comment: Please clarify your question by making it more concrete.